# Why are Visual Studio background threads so slow?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, envdte

I'm trying to update my extension [VSFileNav](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af) to make it work with VS2012 and make some improvements to it. It's supposed to list all the files in a Visual Studio solution, but I'd like to extend this to list methods/symbols too.

I've tried this previously and never got to the bottom of my problems. What I find is that if I enumerate the `Solution->Projects->Project Items` on the main thread it's reasonably quick, however if I try to use any sort of thread things just slow right down. I know symbol searching takes a while from previous attempts that I've not re-implemented yet, but as an example, when trying to find all the `ProjectItem` file names:

> ProcessMainThread took : 7 ms
>   ProcessBackgroundThreadPool took : 6661 ms
>   ProcessCustomThread took : 6750 ms

Snippet of my code to run this, as I've mentioned all it's doing is enumerating all the `ProjectItems` ultimately:

```
public void TimeProcess()
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    ProcessMainThread();
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("ProcessMainThread took : " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

    ProcessBackgroundThreadPool();

    ProcessCustomThread();
}

public void ProcessMainThread() 
{
    Process(); 
}

public void ProcessBackgroundThreadPool()
{
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback((o) => 
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Process();
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("ProcessBackgroundThreadPool took : " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    }));
}
public void ProcessCustomThread() 
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Process();
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("ProcessCustomThread took : " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    }));
    t.Start();
}
```

So my question is, why on earth does it take almost 1000x as long on a thread, and how can I produce a non-blocking function that isn't going to run slowly? - bearing in mind when I start enumerating symbols in files it's going to be much longer than 7ms otherwise I wouldn't care too much...

Answer (score 5):

You are discovering the Law of There-Is-No-Free-Lunch.  A law that frequently applies to trying to use threads in large object models.  Like any big chunk of code, the VS automation object model is not thread-safe.  And is kept safe by COM, the underpinning of VS automation.  Which ensures that the EnvDTE property accessors and methods you use on your worker thread actually run on the thread that created the object.  Thus ensuring thread-safety.

Which involves a great deal of overhead.  Two thread context switches plus the cost of marshaling the method arguments plus the cost of marshaling the result back.  Plus the latency of the owner thread responding to the marshaling request, usually the largest chunk and highly variable since it depends on whatever else it is doing.  Typical slowdown of a marshaled call vs a call that doesn't cross an apartment boundary is x10000, your measurement is close.

You'd normally avoid this kind of overhead by creating the COM object on the worker thread and turning the worker thread in an Single Threaded Apartment to give them a thread-safe home.  But there are at least two reasons that won't work, a threadpool thread is always MTA.  And the ultimate downfall, these EnvDTE objects were not created by your code.  You can do something about the former (Thread.SetApartmentState) but not the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Hans, might be something I need to read up on. So is there any reasonable way to get around this? - the only alternatives I can think of if using threads is slow is to either a) Keep it slow and do some work in the background, b) Try and find a way to route to the main thread (not sure if this can be done using BeginInvoke etc) or c) manually do work in a non-COM way on a background thread.